# Getting permission prompt for accessing microphone after the speech gets recorded

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an app which records the speech of user and then converts it into text format. I am trying to get permission prompt to access the microphone immediately after the user clicks the recording button. But I am getting permission prompt after the speech gets recorded. Where I am going wrong?

Following are *java* and *xml* files:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.ika.speechtotext;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
    }

    public void onBtnClick(View view) {


        if (view.getId() == R.id.imageRecBtn) {

            // Here, 'this' is the current activity i.e; MainActivity
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {

                    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                } else {

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO is an
                    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                    // result of the request.
                }
            }

            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    }

    //recognize the speech
    public void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak something!");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your device doesn't support speech recognition.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //display the speech in text format
    public void onActivityResult (int request_code, int result_code, Intent i) {
        super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, i);

        switch (request_code) {

            case 100:
                if (result_code == RESULT_OK && i != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    text.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    //a toast for fun
    public void onTextClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are a Genius! ;-)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ika.speechtotext">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/myTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Updated code lines**(MainActivity.java):

```
public void onBtnClick(View view) {


    if (view.getId() == R.id.imageRecBtn) {

        //New code lines BEGIN***************************************************************************************************

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //checking the permission status
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                        REQUEST_CODE_RECORD_AUDIO);

            } else {

                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        }
        //New code lines END***************************************************************************************************

    }


}
```

Comment: seems, you are checking another permission: Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS

Comment: @DmitryArc is right, you're looking for READ_CONTACT, and inside that IF you try to check if audio permission is granted, but you do not enter that IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the code which relate to the problems you are seeing:

1. Regardless of whether your app has been granted the record audio permission, it still calls `promptSpeechInput()`.  This should not happen unless you have the permission.  This means it should be called only if `PERMISSION_GRANTED` here or when `onRequestPermissionResult()` is called for the request.
2. The app is checking for `READ_CONTACTS` then requesting `RECORD_AUDIO`.
3. The result of `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` may not be what you expect if the app has never previously requested the permission.  This method should be used only after the app has requested and been denied permission.  It provides you with information on whether or not you should inform the user why the permission is needed (and if they want to be told about it.)

The newer permissions model can be tricky to work with.  You may find this talk on the new model helpful: https://youtu.be/WGz-alwVh8A

You may also find this permissions helper library easier to work with.  It will handle the user prompting under the recommended conditions as well as calling the relevant "protected" code when the app has permission: https://github.com/hiqes/andele

Comment: Thank you for answering. Tutorial link was very helpful. I fixed the permission prompt issue but I want app to start recording speech immediately after the permission granted (for now I have to click the rec button again). _Provided the updated 'MainActivity.java' snippet._

Comment: You still need to add a `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback and if the permission is granted call `promptSpeechInput()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my work PC right now so I can't post the code but I'll give you the steps to do it.

1. When user clicks the record button check if record permission is granted. If yes then call promptSpeechInput() method, else ask for record permission.
2. override [void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, 
               String[] permissions, 
               int[] grantResults)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) method in your activity. Inside this check if requestCode equals to your requestCode for record permission that you asked for. If yes, then check if permission is granted. If it is granted then call promptSpeechInput() method, else do nothing or go back or exit. A rationale isn't required as asking for record permission to record audio is clearly understandable.
   I hope it's clear. Feel free to ask any question related to the steps.